# SApply says an argument does exist when I believe it does

Tags: r, function, machine-learning, sapply

I have a function and a "sub-function" utilized by the outer function.  I'll post the code as it is usually asked but the issue I have is pretty straightforward.  The main function is this:

```
cvKNN = function(dataSet, foldNum) {
dataSet = data$train[, c("X1", "X2", "Y")] ## 200-by-3 training data
foldSize = floor(nrow(dataSet)/foldNum)

KVector = seq(1, (nrow(dataSet) - foldSize), 2)
cvKNNAveErrorRates = sapply(KVector, cvKNNAveErrorRate, dataSet,foldSize, foldNum)
test = cvKNNAveErrorRate()
```

This function takes a dataset of 200-by-3 items that indicate location info for nearest neighbors.
The problem I have is in the line:

```
cvKNNAveErrorRates = sapply(KVector, cvKNNAveErrorRate, dataSet,foldSize, foldNum)
```

cvKNNAveErrorRate is called to calculate error rates for various K values.   This rate would be determined through a bunch of calls for about 30 K's.

```
cvKNNAveErrorRate = function(dataSet, foldSize, foldNum){

error = 0
for (runId in 1:foldNum) {
testSetIndex = ((runId - 1) * foldSize + 1):(ifelse(runId ==
foldNum, nrow(dataSet), runId * foldSize))
trainX = dataSet[-testSetIndex, c("X1", "X2")]
trainY = as.factor(dataSet[-testSetIndex, ]$Y)
testX = dataSet[testSetIndex, c("X1", "X2")]
testY = as.factor(dataSet[testSetIndex, ]$Y)
predictY = knn(trainX, testX, trainY, K)
error = error + sum(predictY != testY)
}
error = error/nrow(dataSet)
error

}
```

The problem is, I'm getting this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'foldNum' not found
```

Why is this happening?  I clearly have foldNum passed into the function from the function above. Why is it not finding it? Is this a scope issue I'm not understanding in R?

Thanks!

Comment: cvKNNAveErrorRate takes three arguments, but with `sapply(KVector, cvKNNAveErrorRate, dataSet,foldSize, foldNum)` you are giving it four. Suggest naming arguments in `sapply`

Comment: Sorry - that doesn't make sense to me. Sapply looks like this:`sapply(X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)` . So `X` is my dataset, `FUN` is the `cvKNNAveErrorRate`, and then I put in 3 additional arguments.  How can I reconcile that with saying I only have 4?  I have the 2 that are necessary, and the 3 I've added optionally as per the `...` in the docs.  I tried doing the naming as follows and I still get the error `cvKNNAveErrorRates = sapply(X=KVector, FUN=cvKNNAveErrorRate, dataSet = dataSet ,foldSize = foldSize, foldNum = foldNum)`.

Comment: I'm with @Richard here. The first argument of sapply (a list or a vector) should be the first argument of the function takes already, you should only gives the two additional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this simple function where we `sample` values from the list :

```
lst <- list(1:4, 13:16)

return_val <- function(x, ...) {
  sample(x, ...)
}
```

Now let's say you want to `sample` 1 element from each list. You can do :

```
sapply(lst, return_val, 1)
#[1]  3 16
```

Notice how this works. `x` value of `return_val` function is the element of the list by default. So for first iteration it would be `lst[[1]]` and for second iteration it would be `lst[[2]]`. Notice that we don't have to explicitly mention `lst` anywhere in the function call here. The second argument which we have passed (`1`) goes as second argument to `sample` function i.e `size`.

We can use an anonymous function without `return_val` and use `sample` directly to understand what is happening. The equivalent of above would be :

```
sapply(lst, function(x) sample(x, 1))
```

Now let's say you want to pass additional arguments to function i.e you want to pass the probabilities. If you do :

```
sapply(lst, return_val, 1, c(0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1))
```

This returns an error that

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
> invalid 'replace' argument

which makes sense since it passes `c(0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1)` as second argument of `sample` which is `replace`. You can reproduce the same error with

```
sapply(lst, function(x) sample(x, 1, c(0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1)))
```

To avoid this error what you'll do is name the argument in `sample` i.e

```
sapply(lst, function(x) sample(x, 1, prob = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1)))
```

and this works as expected.

You need to do the same thing when you are using `...` part of `sapply` and not using an anonymous function. This now works :

```
sapply(lst, return_val, 1, prob = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1))
```

So to conclude how `sapply`/`lapply` works is if you don't name your arguments by default the elements from `X` (i.e `lst` in the example) is the first argument to `FUN` (`return_val` here) and rest of the arguments follow the same order. If you want to change the order of the arguments you have to name them.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally rolled back your changes when I just meant to rollback the spelling of utilize.  Let me look at your comments here and see if I can make sense of it.